# Python pymqi : How to specify the message format for putting to a queue

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I amd trying put a string message in MQ using pymqi, the code is as follows;

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
import pymqi

class PutMQ:
    def put_mq(args1):
        doc = minidom.parse(args1)                       
        queue_manager = "NameQueueManager"
        channel = "ChannelName"
        host = "HostName"
        port = "PortNumber"
        conn_info = "%s(%s)" % (host, port)

        qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)

        qmgr.connectTCPClient(queue_manager, pymqi.cd(), channel, conn_info)

        putq = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, 'QueueName')


        putq.put(doc.toprettyxml())

        putq.close()
        qmgr.disconnect()
    put_mq('C://MQ//myMessage.xml')
```

When I run this code, it doesn't throw any error. Hence, I get the feeling that the message has been put successfully on the required Queue.

However, I am expecting to see a record in one of my application screen after I send the above message to the Queue, and this is not happening.

If I put the same message through AppWatch (web interface), it works and I see the expected record on the application UI too.

On the AppWatch (web interface), when I do the 'Put Message', I mention the message type as : "String Format (MQFMT_STRING)".

How can I specify in my code that the message format is 'MQFMT_STRING'?

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [PyMQI Docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pymqi/api.html) this is the definition of the put call:

> **put(msg[, mDesc, putOpts])**
>
> Put the string buffer ‘msg’ on the queue. If the queue is not already open, it is opened now with the option ‘MQOO_OUTPUT’.
>
> mDesc is the pymqi.md() MQMD Message Descriptor for the message. If it is not passed, or is None, then a default md() object is used.
>
> putOpts is the pymqi.pmo() MQPMO Put Message Options structure for the put call. If it is not passed, or is None, then a default pmo() object is used.
>
> If mDesc and/or putOpts arguments were supplied, they may be updated by the put operation.

So in order to set the format you need to supply an MQMD Message Descriptor, the `mDesc` parameter on the put call.

I haven't tried this out myself, but your code should look something like:

```
md = pymqi.MD()
md.Format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING
putq.put(doc.toprettyxml(), md, None)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you now. Remember to accept the answer (by clicking on the tick) if you thought it solved your problem.