# ERROR: Process message with RFH2 header using python to IBM MQ

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-mq, pymqi

I was trying to send message(with rfh2 header) using python. But getting the below error. Is there a proper way to send the message successfully to MQ? Code is given below.

ERROR:[MWI_B2BTransactionLogger|A|M|FC]DataError - Input WMQ message missing the MQRFH2/usr - MQMD USR folder:

```
import pymqi
qm_name='Axxx'
channel='Gxxxx'
host='uxxxx'
port='1xx'
conn_info='%s(%s)' % (host, port)

file_name="/xxxxx/Test01_InsertSucess01.dat"
q_name="Axxxxx.FLOWQ"


qm=pymqi.QueueManager(None)
qm.connectTCPClient(qm_name,pymqi.cd(),channel,conn_info)
queue=pymqi.Queue(qm,q_name)
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
  data=f.read()

queue.put(data)
queue.close()
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995534/python-pymqi-how-to-specify-the-message-format-for-putting-to-a-queue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pymqi : How to specify the message format for putting to a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995534/python-pymqi-how-to-specify-the-message-format-for-putting-to-a-queue)

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Why do you want to send a message as an RFH2 message?

(1) I don't see anywhere in your code that you are setting the MQMD Format field.
(2) I don't see the creation of the MQRFH2 header and folders in the code.
i.e.

```
rfh2 = pymqi.RFH2()
```